# Psychometric Meta-Analysis in R

Tags: r, meta-analysis, psychometrics

I would like to perform a psychometric meta-analysis of stigma measurement instruments. A potential candidate for a specific analytical approach could be in my opinion the Hunter and Schmidt method: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:hunter_schmidt_method. This method aims to explain a proportion of artifact or measurement error in an instrument (i.e., test measuring attitudes, job performance, etc.). You can find an example here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1744-6570.1991.tb00688.x/full (older article in Personnel Psychology Journal). These methods are sometimes also called validity (or reliability) generalization procedures.

I would like to apply this particular method in R and what I was hoping to find was an analytical example of how to apply the procedure in R. I've found that metafor package seems to include some of the Hunter-Schmidt formulas; however, does not offer any examples (such as here): http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses. Psychometric meta-analyses seem to be not as common as for example meta-analyses of Randomised Control Trials.

I would be grateful if anyone would be able to refer me to a good example of how was the procedure mentioned above conducted, ideally in R. Or offer some hints, tips to start such a meta-analysis.

**Edit**: Based on suggestions from users, here's a brief example of how data may look like and what would be the aim or objective of meta-analysis. At this stage, I am unable to provide a real-world example, therefore the snippet below shows data set through generic example. These examples assume that all scales measure the same or similar construct; however, they might differ in the content and score range.

Example with same validity evidence and reliability measures:

```
Name of Scale       Validity evidence              Reliability measure
Scale A             Correlation coefficient        Cronbach's Alpha
Scale B             Correlation coefficient        Cronbach's Alpha
Scale C             Correlation coefficient        Cronbach's Alpha
```

Example with different validity evidence and reliability measures:

```
Name of Scale       Validity evidence              Reliability measure
Scale A             Correlation coefficient        Cronbach's Alpha
Scale B             Confirmatory Factor Analysis   Omega coefficient
Scale C             Content validity               Cronbach's Alpha
```

The meta-analytical aim would be to generalize validity evidence of Scale A to C and say to what extent these instruments provide **a)** sufficient validity evidence; similarly, regarding reliability, it would be to say to what extent are these instruments **b)** precise on a general level. Ideally, I would be able to take into account **c)** sociodemographic characteristics of samples these instruments used and explain a proportion of artifact or measurement error across instruments. I am not an experienced user regarding psychometric meta-analysis so this example may not necessarily be sufficient, apologies in advance.

Comment: Do you just need to meta-analyze psychometric data, or do you need some particular method or family of methods called "psychometric meta-analysis"? If the former, why not use generic meta-analytic methods?

Comment: @Kodiologist If by psychometric data you mean evidence of reliability such as Cronbach's alpha and validity such as correlation - then yes, it's psychometric data. However; when I did my research on this topic, I've found good results **only** when focusing on "psychometric meta-analysis" such as the one described by Hunter-Schmidt. So I came to the conclusion that to analyse such data I need to approach it in a similar direction. Either way, I still don't know how would I approach such data with either "generic" or "psychometric" meta-analysis, hence the question.

Comment: What  do you mean by RCT ? And what is its expansion ?

Comment: Please indicate data that you want to analyse and tell your key objective you want to realize with the  help of meta-analysis ?

Comment: Before your edit I had been  thinking to answer -  "generic " Vs. Psychometric method . Your edit is helpful. I want to know whether you want to ascertain common effect -size or variability in effect -sizes generated by  different instruments. May be   you want  to meta-analyze the reliabilies of different instruments !  Or anything else .

Comment: For questions which revolve around R packages for meta-analysis you might get a better response on the mailing list dedicated to that topic https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// You need to register first. Having said that the package psychmeta may be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ Gofraith you should indicate your data and objectives if you want guidance ?  Links can not be used as a basis to help you out.Different formulas and approaches are available in the book by Hunter, Schmidt and Jackson (1982) and  Hunter and Schmidt (2004). My articles in the context of meta analysis are available  on Ebscohost.

Comment: A brief desription of your own problem and data should help the users of this site  to answer your questions. It is difficult to discern your objectives and type of effect-sizes.

Comment: @subhashc.davar I tried my best to provide such an example and edited the original post, but it might not be good enough. I am afraid I can't-do more at this stage. When possible I'll try to edit it to provide a better example.

Answer (score 3):

The psychmeta package (http://cran.r-project.org/package=psychmeta) has implemented a wide array of psychometric meta-analysis models.

The ma_r() function implements a variety of psychometric meta-analysis models for correcting for sampling error, measurement error, range restriction, and other artifacts.

For an overview of the package, run vignette("overview", package = "psychmeta") in R.

Comment: That's more of a helpful comment than an answer.  If you mean it to be an answer, then provide "a good example of how was the procedure mentioned above conducted, ideally in R. Or offer some hints, tips to start such a meta-analysis."

Comment: I provided more detail on how to access the tutorial on using the package, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hunter and Schmidt (1990) and 2004 as well as Hunter, Schmidt and Jackson (1982) and othes eg Borenstein have postulated several meta-analytic approaches - psychometric approaches. The choice of a technique depends on the goal of your study (eg. Validity generalization)  and the data ( here effect sizes, reliability coefficients, sample sizes of studies design of study etc.) at hand. You seem to be interested in validity generalization of stigma scale ! Look for an appriate "psychometric" meta analysis  method like that of Hunter and Schmidt (2004) or some other methods. It is not too important to execute formulas in R specifically.